# Is it possible to paginate STDOUT?

Tags: linux, shell, file-io, split, stdin

Is it possible to split STDIN (or STDOUT) so that the next program in a pipeline might be able to interpret the stream as multiple files?

Specifically I would like to split `git log -p` output into individual commits in the pager `less`, as if I had started it with multiple files and could `:n` through the commits so it's clearer where one ends and the next begins.

Comment: What's the problem with the space key?  Isn't it easier than `:n`?

Comment: Yes, space/PgDn both scroll down, but it's easy to go beyond the end of the current commit or miss it; I want a "harder" stop between commits for clarity's sake.  Currently I search for "^commit" to make it stand out better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible to actually split `stdout`.

However, one way to achieve what you want is to split a file of the output of `git log -p` on some pattern (say `commit`) and then form a set of files representing each commit. These files can then be browsed in order. You'll need the `csplit` command to do the splitting:

```
csplit -zqf "commit-" <(git log -p) '/^commit /' '{*}' && less commit-*
```

This tries to split the git command output on the regex pattern an arbitrary number of times - hence the `{*}` - and for each match puts the result in a file. The resulting files - if any - has the form `commit-n` and are created in the current directory. They can then be browsed in order with `less` from the newest to the oldest commit.

To fully understand the `csplit` options, lookup `man csplit`.

Comment: Thanks, Herman.  I actually discovered csplit just after I asked the question.  Splitting STDOUT by using sed to inject some kind of control character was my first idea, but it doesn't look like that's possible.

Comment: The regular expression can also be `/^.\[33mcommit /` when using the `--color` option to git and the ANSI colors will be preserved.